# How to retrieve order ID on Order Pay page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to modify the Woocomerce checkout page for orders that are failed or pending payment. On those orders the system comes to the checkout with an order already generated, but I am not able to retrieve the ID of that order from the *form_checkout.php* template.

Failed orders can be paid by the customer with the Woocommerce URL, similar to the following one:

```
https://myurl.com/checkout/order-pay/XXXXX/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_XXXXXXXXXXXX&subscription_renewal=true
```

Neither do I retrieve the variables with a $_GET since the URL is transformed into *https://myurl.com/checkout* when accessing. I don't know if you lose this data or where I can collect it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve the order Id on Order pay page you will use the following:

```
global $wp;

if ( isset($wp->query_vars['order-pay']) && absint($wp->query_vars['order-pay']) > 0 ) {
    $order_id = absint($wp->query_vars['order-pay']); // The order ID

    $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get the WC_Order Object instance
}
```

**Note:** To target Order pay page, you can use `is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay')` conditional tag.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, it's just what I was looking for. I am very grateful for your response.

Comment: However, using *is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay')* I have the same problem, the endpoint is lost in the URL, which looks something like this: myurl.com/checkout/

Answer (score 0):

`$order = wc_get_order(get_query_var('order-pay'));`